# undecomposability of a non-negative integer matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I am looking for an algorithm to test whether a non-negative dxd integer matrix is undecomposable. I call a matrix *undecomposable* if it can not be written as a product of two non-negative dxd integer matrices none of them being a permutation matrix (ie not invertible in the semiring of non-negative integer matrices SL_d(N)). I am mostly interested in the case of 3x3 matrices with determinant 1. Note that the case of 1x1 matrices correspond to ask wether a positive integer is prime. For the case of 2x2 matrices with determinant 1 it is well known that the only non-decomposable matrices are the permutation matrices and the elementary matrices (this is because the elementary matrices generate the whole SL_2(N)). There are infinitely many known examples of undecomposable matrices in SL_3(N) (J. Rivat "Undecomposable matrices in dimension 3" appendix in Pytheas Fogg "Substitutions in Dynamics, Arithmetics and Combinatorics", Springer LNM).

There is a naive algorithm which consists at looking at a more general factorisation of the form BC = A with B a d x k matrix and C a k x d matrix. That way we may start a recursive construction. We fill the first column of B by B0 and the first line of C by C0 in such way that B0 * C0 <= A (here I mean all coefficients are smaller). Then it is enough to find B' and C' of size respectively d x (k-1) and (k-1) x d such that B' * C' = A - B0*C0. This algorithm is relatively slow!

The equations associated to the problem are quadratic with 2 d^2 variables (d^2 for A and d^2 for B) and I want to solve them with non-negative integers. As the equations are of very special form, I guess that there might be some better way to solve them or at least to make the recursive construction more efficient.

Comment: Can you formalize your question a bit more? For a given matrix M you want to know if there exist matrices A and B such that M = A x B ? There is always a trivial solution A = Identity, B = M, so NO matrix is indecomposable...

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry Right! I mean non-trivial solution (as you would do for integer factorization). Thanks.

Comment: How would you define non-trivial? Does that mean that neither A or B can be diagonal?

Comment: @MarcClaesen Yes they may. But if the initial matrix M has determinant one then the only diagonal matrix which can appear is the identity. It is definitely the most interesting case and the one in which I am interested in!

Comment: Any multiple of the identity would work too, though I guess that's trivial.

Comment: @MarcClaesen No they would not. Recall that I want solutions which are integer matrices. We have det(A) det(B) = det(M) and all these numbers are **integers**. So if det(M) = 1 then A and B have automatically determinant +1 or -1.

Comment: For `d > 1`, you can always write `M = P*(P^(-1)*M)` where `P` is a nontrivial permutation matrix, a matrix with exactly one `1` in each row and each column, `0` everywhere else. The inverse of a permutation matrix is again a permutation matrix, so, if I didn't misunderstand your requirements, the only indecomposable ones would be 1×1 prime matrices. You might want to exclude permutation matrices too.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want non trivial solution: none of B or C is invertible... I update the question.

Comment: I suspected you wanted more stringent constraints than just "two non-negative dxd integer matrices different from identity". I'm not sure you need to go as far as excluding all invertible matrices, generally, it would still be difficult to avoid negative entries.

Comment: @DanielFischer: you are right!

Comment: I recommend you post this on mathoverflow.  Also, make it clear whether you want a factorization if it exists, or you just want a yes/no answer whether the matrix is indecomposable.  For 1x1, primality testing can be done in polynomial time (using some somewhat heavy number theory, hence why yours is arguably a math question), but actually producing a factorization of a non-prime number is suspected to be hard (either NP-complete, or somewhere between NP-complete and P).  Also if you are willing to assume a bound on the entries of your matrix (to make things faster), make that known too.

Answer (score 0):

ok i try to write the problem as i see it:

```
M = A x B
```

- M known non negative integer input matrix NxN
- A,B unknown output decomposition of M, non unit, non negative integer

multiplication of matrixes:

```
M[i][j] = sum(k=0,1,...,N-1)A[i][k]*B[k][j]
```

ok now let me write an 3x3 example for clarity:

```
M[3][3]=A*B

  i  j    i  k    k  j    i  k    k  j    i  k    k  j
M[0][0]=A[0][0]*B[0][0]+A[0][1]*B[1][0]+A[0][2]*B[2][0]
M[0][1]=A[0][0]*B[0][1]+A[0][1]*B[1][1]+A[0][2]*B[2][1]
M[0][2]=A[0][0]*B[0][2]+A[0][1]*B[1][2]+A[0][2]*B[2][2]
M[1][0]=A[1][0]*B[0][0]+A[1][1]*B[1][0]+A[1][2]*B[2][0]
M[1][1]=A[1][0]*B[0][1]+A[1][1]*B[1][1]+A[1][2]*B[2][1]
M[1][2]=A[1][0]*B[0][2]+A[1][1]*B[1][2]+A[1][2]*B[2][2]
M[2][0]=A[2][0]*B[0][0]+A[2][1]*B[1][0]+A[2][2]*B[2][0]
M[2][1]=A[2][0]*B[0][1]+A[2][1]*B[1][1]+A[2][2]*B[2][1]
M[2][2]=A[2][0]*B[0][2]+A[2][1]*B[1][2]+A[2][2]*B[2][2]
// usage of B[i][j]
M[0][0]=A[0][0]*B[0][0]+...
M[1][0]=A[1][0]*B[0][0]+...
M[2][0]=A[2][0]*B[0][0]+...
M[?][j]=A[?][i]*B[i][j]+...
// usage of A[i][j]
M[0][0]=A[0][0]*B[0][0]+...
M[0][1]=A[0][0]*B[0][1]+...
M[0][2]=A[0][0]*B[0][2]+...
M[i][?]=A[i][j]*B[j][?]+...
```

When you look closer then the solution is very simple. find all:

```
A[i][j]=GCD(M[i][0],...,M[i][N-1])
```

then derive B either from M,A or as B=M*inverse(A)

M is decomposable if there is at least single A[i][j] > 1

also you can get B as GCD and derivate A from M,B,....

thats all , hope it helps...